# A new session could not be created in Appium

Tags: appium

I'm new to Appium. I'm facing this error and my App not launching when starting the Appium server.
Could anyone help me on this.

Here is the error I'm getting on Appium server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYBCA.jpg)

Here is the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCi2m.jpg)

Please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide error messages and code as text and not as code.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the application manually or through ADB.  The error message explains that the existing version is incompatible with the version you're trying to run/install, so you need to uninstall it manually first.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot you are using very old `Appium.exe` which is **no longer supported** and there is no way its gonna work with Android 7 device.

You have to use [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases) or install/run server via command line:

`npm install -g appium`

`appium`